# What happened to psycopg2.sql?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

In the psycopg2 docs it references an [sql](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) property full of fun goodness for *safely* constructing SQL strings. Yet my install on python 3, which should be latest from PyPI, contains no such attribute:

```
from psycopg2 import sql
# ImportError: cannot import name 'sql'

import psycopg2
print(dir(psycopg2)) # no mention of sql, although dir is not complete

# in the REPL
help(psycopg2) # no mention of the sql submodule that I saw
```

So how can I safely construct SQL strings without it (I have zero interest in SQLAlchemy)? Or should I still have that and the fact that its missing is worrisome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is new in Psycopg2 2.7. What is your version?

```
>>> psycopg2.__version__
'2.6.2 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)'
```

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html

Comment: Just checked `pip freeze`, I'm on 2.6.2. Oops.