# Python3, submodule problem - ImportError: cannot import name 'sql'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use some code that requires Python3

I already use Python (version 2) for something else so I got things working by using *python3* instead of *python* when installing various modules

```
sudo apt install python3-docopt
sudo apt install python3-requests
sudo apt install python3-lxml
sudo apt install python3-psycopg2
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install tqdm
```

and that worked for the first program I run. But now another program (from the same repository) complains about *sql* module within *psycopg2*, although psycopg2 and sql modules are imported.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~/code/discogs-xml2db/speedup$ sudo pip3 install sql
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): sql in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~/code/discogs-xml2db/speedup$ sudo apt install python3-sql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-sql is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 359 not upgraded.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~/code/discogs-xml2db/speedup$ python3 discogs-import.py ../csv/*
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "discogs-import.py", line 6, in <module>
        from psycopg2 import sql
    ImportError: cannot import name 'sql'
```

I dont understand what I have to do to resolve this ?

Trying to do form console also failed

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~/code/discogs-xml2db/speedup$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 12 2018, 22:25:49)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from psycopg2 import sql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'sql'
>>> from python3-psycopg2 import sql
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from python3-psycopg2 import sql
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~/code/discogs-xml2db/speedup$ sudo apt install python3-psycopg2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-psycopg2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 359 not upgraded.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~/code/discogs-xml2db/speedup$ pip3 show python3-psycopg2
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~/code/discogs-xml2db/speedup$ pip3 show psycopg2
---
Name: psycopg2
Version: 2.4.5
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires:
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~/code/discogs-xml2db/speedup$ pip show psycopg2
---
Name: psycopg2
Version: 2.4.5
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~/code/discogs-xml2db/speedup$
```

Comment: Have you tried starting python3 in terminal and running the import command there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From psycopg2 import sql not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031075/from-psycopg2-import-sql-not-working)

Comment: @Nanna tried now didnt work, added to my question

Comment: @tomgalpin no it doesnt really

Comment: [psycopg2.sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) is available since version 2.7, you got 2.4.5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883389/what-happened-to-psycopg2-sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happened to psycopg2.sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883389/what-happened-to-psycopg2-sql)

Comment: @Nanna maybe, so how do I get later version of psycopg2 ?

Comment: I would use pip3 to install it, and do ´pip3 install psycopg2 -U´ to get the latest version

Comment: @PaulTaylor You can specify which version to install using `pip install <package-name>==<version-no>`

Comment: ok, sudo pip3 install psycopg2 -U seems to have worked, not sure why didnt install latets version by default.

Answer (score -1):

You need to import it in a different way:

```
from psycopg2 import sql
```

The result is:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from psycopg2 import sql
>>>
```

**Furthermore take care of selecting the right python environment.**
It might result in complications installing packages through `pip` with `sudo`.

Using `sudo pip` installs into the root user environment while using just `python script.py` to call your script uses the user environment.

---

I installed it into a virtual environment using:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Comment: I tried that above, didnt work